# Checking if Parse.com class is (undefined)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, undefined

I'm trying to catch an exception. I thought that checking whether the String is empty would help, but it doesn't seem to work. The value in the actual column for the object in my class is "(undefined)". It seems to be that by default. How can I explicitly check to see if it is undefined?

```
notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FEED_TYPE).isEmpty()
```

Heads up. The following doesn't work either:

```
notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FEED_TYPE).equals("(undefined)");
```

Comment: try to debugging and see whats the value notifications.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_FEED_TYPE) gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's checking using Android default function like

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notifications.get(ParseConstants.KEY_FEED_TYPE))) {
        // its not null value success
    } else {
        // here getting to null value Fail
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. Instead of looking for a String (in which case the field entry would be truly empty, and not `(undefined)`), I checked to see if the object was null after dropping the String from getString.

```
if (notifications.get(ParseConstants.KEY_FEED_TYPE) != null) {

    // Do something.

} else {

    // Do something else.

}
```